# set and get default directory in html using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a question on how to set and get a default directory in javascript or jquery. The fact is that I've make some research on Google and this seems to be impossible. But I want to go through another way it's mean i want to copy all my Data from the server to a workstation, so that I can define the initial directory of my workstation in html. I wait to have a workstation before To try it but I doubt whether it is possible or not. That's why I'm asking you the question. Has anyone tried this method if it works? If so, share your experience with me. I want to try something like this and D:\Users... will be the initial directory from my workstation that i want to set in my html-code. Thank you in advance.

```
 <input type="file" id="filepath" value="D:\Users\Folder1\Folder2\..."  webkitdirectory directory multiple />
```

Comment: If you want the server to write files to a specific location on the workstation hard disk, you'll need node.js for this. The file API is designed to provide the opposite, have the workstation mark files you want to upload to the server. Front-side html/JS, even when run on the server, cannot access the hard disk of other computers. Could you explain a little more detailed which steps should be taken? Eg: admin opens webpage, admin drag and drops all files he want to write to the workstation, admin presses some button and workstation gets files written to it?

Comment: Eg: The sever must constainly communicate with the workstation. The User click on button choose file from input-file and the directory from the workstation that i've set will be open allowing the user to select folder containing files. The selected directory must be show in the textarea of the input-file control.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I udnerstand correctly. But the default directory shown in the file path is the last directory opened on the default defined in the operating system. It's probably not possible apart from using hacks that will make the app completely insecure.

Comment: can you tell me more about using hacks even if it 'll make the webpage insecure? FYI i currently work with webstorm and node.js Express. Thanks a lot

Comment: Since the directory shown is either the default or the last one selected, if you manage to 'fake' a form submit, the path inside the value attribute should be set as the path used the enxt time the upload button is clicked. But that violates browser policies, so you'll have to find a way to allow that automatic submit.

Comment: An other thing you could try is not using a file upload. If the workstation shares it's c-drive with the node server, the node server should be able to grab the directory structure of the workstation hard disk. You can then show a list of all the file names inside the directory you want and have the user select one of those strings. Then have the server fetch that file from the drive instead. SO absically turn your logic around. Instead of having the html page determine the files and uploading them, have the html page select file names that the node server will then move.

Comment: the first priority is to set and get the last selected folder and 2ndly to upload file.